# Merging Sentinel 2 RGB bands with rasterio

Tags: rasterio

I'm trying to merge Sentinel 2 bands RGB bands with rasterio like this:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterio import plot
from rasterio.plot import show

band2=rasterio.open("B02.jp2")
band3=rasterio.open("B03.jp2")
band4=rasterio.open("B04.jp2")

rgb=rasterio.open('rgb.tiff', 'w', driver='Gtiff',
                          width=band2.width, height=band2.height,
                          count=3,
                          crs=band2.crs,
                          transform=band2.transform,
                          dtype='uint16')
rgb.write(band4.read(1),1)
rgb.write(band3.read(1),2)
rgb.write(band2.read(1),3)
rgb.close()
```

This works as expected and creates a RGB-GeoTIFF that is properly displayed in QGIS. However if I try to visualize it with rasterio, I get an almost black image:

```
show(plot.adjust_band(rasterio.open('rgb.tiff').read([1,2,3])))
```

when I inspect the normalized values the mean for each band is around 0.05. Is there something wrong how I create the RGB?

Comment: please check the nodata value of your bands. maybe 65535  it is considered as a value so that the adjustment is not done on the correct range. rasterio plot options are unfortunately quite limited, while QGIS does it better.This is not a merging but a display isse as far as I can tell from your explanations.

Comment: The pixel values before the normalization are between 1 and around 28000. The relevant output of gdalinfo doesn't yield infos about no_data: 
`Band 1 Block=10980x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=10980x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 3 Block=10980x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined`

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same "issue" when working on Sentinel-2 images. Your code looks fine but incomplete. QGIS automatically rescales image intensity, which explains why your images is displayed correctly. However, rasterio does not proceed likewise, so you need to **rescale image intensity** before plotting. I suggest you to use `skimage` for achieving it. See the following code (worked well for me):

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterio import plot
from rasterio.plot import show
from skimage import exposure

band2=rasterio.open("B02.jp2")
band3=rasterio.open("B03.jp2")
band4=rasterio.open("B04.jp2")

band2_geo = band2.profile
band2_geo.update({"count": 3})

with rasterio.open('rgb.tiff', 'w', **band2_geo) as dest:
# I rearanged the band order writting to 2→3→4 instead of 4→3→2
    dest.write(band2.read(1),1)
    dest.write(band3.read(1),2)
    dest.write(band4.read(1),3)

# Rescale the image (divide by 10000 to convert to [0:1] reflectance
img = rasterio.open('rgb.tiff')
image = np.array([img.read(3), img.read(2), img.read(1)]).transpose(1,2,0)
p2, p98 = np.percentile(image, (2,98))
image = exposure.rescale_intensity(image, in_range=(p2, p98)) / 100000

# Plot the RGB image
show(image.transpose(2,0,1), transform=img.transform)
```

Comment: Awesome, I've been looking for this. Do you know this issue exists? C

Comment: Can the data range for the bands be transformed in values between 0-255?