# Write three band RGB to file

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm trying to create a 3 band RGB image from Sentinel 2 bands but I seem to be trying to write an array of inconsistent shape:

For example:

> ValueError: Source shape (1, 10980, 10980, 3) is inconsistent with
> given indexes 1

I've tried reshaping it but I still get errors.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio, os

folder = r"/home/bera/data/Sentinel2/S2B_MSIL2A_20200625T101559_N0214_R065_T33VWD_20200625T134347.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T33VWD_A017251_20200625T101903/IMG_DATA/R10m/"
bluefile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VWD_20200625T101559_B02_10m.jp2")
greenfile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VWD_20200625T101559_B03_10m.jp2")
redfile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VWD_20200625T101559_B04_10m.jp2")

#Read as datasets
dsblue = rasterio.open(bluefile)
dsgreen = rasterio.open(greenfile)
dsred = rasterio.open(redfile)

#And to arrays
blue = dsblue.read(1)
green = dsgreen.read(1)
red = dsred.read(1)

#Composite 
rgb = np.dstack((red, green, blue))
print(rgb.shape)
#(10980, 10980, 3)

def writetofile(output, array):
    with rasterio.open(fp=outfile, mode="w", driver="GTiff", 
                       width=rgb.shape[1], height=rgb.shape[0],
                       count=3, crs=dsblue.crs, 
                       transform=dsblue.transform, dtype=rgb.dtype) as dst:
        dst.write(array, 3)

outfile = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/rgbtest.tif"
writetofile(output=outfile, array=rgb)
#ValueError: Source shape (1, 10980, 10980, 3) is inconsistent with given indexes 1

from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_raster, reshape_as_image

raster = reshape_as_raster(rgb)
print(raster.shape)
#(3, 10980, 10980)
writetofile(output=outfile, array=raster)
#ValueError: Source shape (1, 3, 10980, 10980) is inconsistent with given indexes 1

image = reshape_as_image(rgb)
print(image.shape)
#(10980, 3, 10980)
writetofile(output=outfile, array=image)
#ValueError: Source shape (1, 10980, 3, 10980) is inconsistent with given indexes 1
```

Comment: What happens with `dst.write(array)` or `dst.write(array, [1,2,3])` (or 0,1,2?) instead?

Comment: All bands got the value zero, or I got the `Source shape error`. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341809/merging-sentinel-2-rgb-bands-with-rasterio) that it is possible to write the bands one by one to the same output file, you dont need to stack them.

This is working:

```
import rasterio, os

folder = r"C:\S2_230731\S2A_MSIL2A_20230611T103631_N0509_R008_T33VUH_20230611T173458\S2A_MSIL2A_20230611T103631_N0509_R008_T33VUH_20230611T173458.SAFE\GRANULE\L2A_T33VUH_A041618_20230611T103626\IMG_DATA\R10m"
bluefile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VUH_20230611T103631_B02_10m.jp2")
greenfile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VUH_20230611T103631_B03_10m.jp2")
redfile = os.path.join(folder, "T33VUH_20230611T103631_B04_10m.jp2")

outfile = r"C:\folder\rgbtest.tif"

ds2=rasterio.open(bluefile)
ds3=rasterio.open(greenfile)
ds4=rasterio.open(redfile)
b2 = ds2.read(1)
b3 = ds3.read(1)
b4 = ds4.read(1)

with rasterio.open(fp=outfile, mode="w", driver="GTiff", width=ds2.shape[1], height=ds2.shape[0], 
                   count=3, crs=ds2.crs, transform=ds2.transform, dtype=b2.dtype) as dst:
    dst.write(b2, 3)
    dst.write(b3, 2)
    dst.write(b4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look a the [docs for the write function](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio._io.html#rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write).
The second argument:

> indexes (int or list, optional) – Which bands of the dataset to write to. The default is all.

Here when you pass the value 3, you're asking rasterio to write only the third band.
`dst.write(array)` should work for a `shape == (3, 10980, 10980)`.
For 2d arrays (single band) the right way to do it is with `dst.write_band(1, b4)`.

Edit: just saw the comment above. If `write(array)` produces only zeros, you may have a problem elsewhere.
Possibly because of the reading part, and the JP2 driver.
You can try this:

```py
with rasterio.open(bluefile) as ds2:
    b2 = ds2.read(1)
    profile = ds2.profile.copy()
with rasterio.open(greenfile) as ds3:
    b3 = ds3.read(1)
with rasterio.open(redfile) as ds4:
    b4 = ds4.read(1)

array = np.stack((b4,b3,b2))
print(array.shape)

print(profile)
profile["count"] = 3
profile["driver"] = "GTiff"

with rasterio.open(outfile, "w", **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdal_array
import numpy as np

# input

band2 = gdal.Open(r'My inputpath')
band3 = gdal.Open(r'My inputpath')
band4 = gdal.Open(r'My inputpath')

array2 = band2.ReadAsArray()
array3 = band3.ReadAsArray()
array4 = band4.ReadAsArray()


stack = np.array([array2,array3,array4])

gdal_array.SaveArray(stack, r'My outputpath", prototype=band2)
                     
banda2 = None
```